# Подсчет шагов (Android)

Tags: java, android

Мое приложение должно подсчитывать пройденные пользователем шаги. Подскажите, какие существуют алгоритмы, подходы, API для этого?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324356/how-to-calculate-exact-foot-step-count-using-accelerometer-in-android

Comment: Получите доступ к акселерометру и замеряйте. Как я понимаю, Вы хотите написать свой шагомер, потому что чем то не устраивают другие, поэтому зачем опираться на готовое решение? Делайте исследования сами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для подсчёта шагов вам может помочь библиотека: https://github.com/bagilevi/android-pedometer

---

Также есть официальный пример: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BatchStepSensor

> Sample demonstrating how to set up SensorEventListeners for step detectors and step counters.

<sub>[Источник 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324356/how-to-calculate-exact-foot-step-count-using-accelerometer-in-android)</sub>
<sub>[Источник 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367402/android-4-4-step-detector-and-counter)</sub>